# Converting lines from dxf to polygons

Tags: qgis, dxf

I have several dxf files. Each file, contains the 0 layer. The 0 layer contains lines (which make a closed polygon). In each dxf the lines have their color and line width.
I do not have AutoCAD or anything else like it.
I have QGIS 1.7.4.
I can put these dxf files into vector layers (as line vector) into QGIS.

I do not know the way (using QGIS 1.7.4 ):

1. To turn each vector layer (with lines) to vector layer with polygon.
   To “copy” some of these polygons (vector layers) into a new vector layer.
2. Can each polygon into the new vector layer to have different border color?

Answer (score 3):

In QGIS, you better work with shapefiles. If you import the dxf as layer, you can save it as shapefile, add that to the canvas, and work with that instead of the imported layer.

Lines and polygons are treated seperately in shapefiles. So you need a line file and a polygon file. You can transform lines to polygons with `Vector -> Geometry tools -> Vector to polygon`.

For coloring, you can set the color according to a data field with rightclick on the layer -> Properties, Style tab